# Can't Create Client Server Socket Program in Php

Tags: php, sockets

I am working on Client Server Socket Program for chat like application, but it is giving following error message

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use.... Could not bind to address on line 15

I have seen various tutorials, but i want Server to listen to client request continuously. I have seen port number it is open also but still the same message. I am stuck at this point for several days could not get proper solutions. Please help to solve it thanks.....

Server.php:

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    /* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
    set_time_limit(0);

    /* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
     * as it comes in. */
    ob_implicit_flush();

    $address = 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX';
    $port = 15213;

    if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
        echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
    }

    if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
        echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
    }

    if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
        echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
    }

    do {
        if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
            echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
            break;
        }
        /* Send instructions. */
        $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
            "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

        do {
            if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
                echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
                break 2;
            }
            if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($buf == 'quit') {
                break;
            }
            if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
                socket_close($msgsock);
                break 2;
            }
            $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";
            socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
            echo "$buf\n";
        } while (true);
        socket_close($msgsock);
    } while (true);

    socket_close($sock);
    ?>
```

Client.php

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "<h2>TCP/IP Connection</h2>\n";

/* Get the port for the WWW service. */
$service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');

/* Get the IP address for the target host. */
$address = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

$in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
$out = '';

echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
echo "OK.\n";

echo "Reading response:\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    echo $out;
}

echo "Closing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
echo "OK.\n\n";
?>
```

Comment: Are client and server creating the same port on the same machine? That is not going to work.

Comment: @Seb But in various other examples i have seen client and server are using same port on the same machine.. Can u point out the mistake in my code.

Comment: As Baalthasarr points out in his answer. The server creates the port, the client uses it. Im going to edit my comment to make it better.

Comment: @Seb As i am new to Socket Programming can u give me a link of any tutorial where server keeps on listening client requests without closing or edit my above code so that i can understand. Thanks...

Comment: @Seb: I have Copied the code from PHP manual but the server is not displaying the output properly and after running some time it displays following error Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in 18, I have edited my code.

Comment: do you use the same ip? in both files?

Comment: I have tested your script with xampp at localhost. so IP was 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

In both php files you create a Socket on the same port. That is the problem.

The Server has to create the Socket while the client has to use the Socket (not creating it, too)

Two applications can not create the same socket and listen on the same port.

**EDIT:**
I have tested your script with xampp at localhost. so IP was 127.0.0.1. The Server listened properly on port 15213 and the client connected properly on this port.
That the port was open i saw with the xampp controll panel.

If you use your scripts like you posted here, then you have to replace in Server.php

```
$address = 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX';
```

with

```
$address = '127.0.0.1';
```

and in Client.php

```
$address = gethostbyname('www.example.com');
```

with

```
$address = gethostbyname('localhost');
or
$address = '127.0.0.1';
```

Comment: Thanks.. But in various tutorials i have seen client and server using the same ports for the connection, so i must use one port for client and other port for server. Or you can give me any other tutorials of client server where server keeps on listening client request without closing.

Comment: In server you listen on the port, in client you connect to the port. In both cases the port is the same, but worked differently.

Comment: @Marek: I have copied the code from PHP Manual but the server does not displays any output and it keeps on running and after running some time it displays following error Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in 18,I have edited my code.

Comment: @user3812616 Now I see you are trying to bind to port 80. Don't you have another webserver (eg apache) running?

Comment: @Marek: I am running this on main server Centos OS 15213 is the port which i have to use. So where i have to make changes in my code.

Comment: @user3812616 In Client.php you have `getservbyname('www', 'tcp');` That's not 15213. But in server you use this port.

Comment: So in client file i should change port to 15213 i.e. $service_port=15213 correct any other problem in the code.

Comment: @Marek: I have changed the port number but after running server and client for some time it gives following error :Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in Line 18. Address already in use. I have requested hostgator for the port no. and i have used netstat to check for this port number but it is not displaying there

Comment: @Marek: Please help to solve this issue. I am dealing with this issue for the past few days ad could not get why this error is coming.